# Hibernate session gets flushed when using hibernate validation

Tags: hibernate, bean-validation, spring-transactions

I am using JSR-303 validation in hibernate. I have created a custom validator annotation which checks for data integrity by querying the database.

**For example:**

```
public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if(value == null){
        return true;
    }
    //This method uses entityManager to fetch a list from database
    Map<String, String> pickList = pickListProvider.getPickList(picklistName);
    return pickList.contains(value);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public class UserProfile extends Persistent {
    //Member fields come here

    @PicklistConstraint(name="languages")
    private String prefLanguage;
}
```

Here UserProfile is an entity persisted using Hibernate. Hibernate calls this validation at pre insert or pre update. However when the validator tries to fetch records from the database, hibernate is flushing the session. Since the domain object on which validation runs is not fully baked (doesn't have Id field), I get the following exception

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in <domain object here> entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1186)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1241)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:257)
```

Upon investigation I found that flushMightBeNeeded of DefaultAutoFlushEventListener returns true:

```
private boolean flushMightBeNeeded(final EventSource source) {
    return !source.getFlushMode().lessThan(FlushMode.AUTO) &&
            source.getDontFlushFromFind() == 0 &&
            ( source.getPersistenceContext().getEntityEntries().size() > 0 ||
                    source.getPersistenceContext().getCollectionEntries().size() > 0 );
}
```

The issue is that FlushMode is AUTO and source.getPersistenceContext().getEntityEntries().size() has some entries.
What should be my approach in such a scenario? Should I change the FlushMode from AUTO to MANUAL? Is it possible to get an new session or persistent context, different from the actual entity?
I am using spring mvc along with hibernate.

**Edit**

I found that source.getPersistenceContext().getEntityEntries() has the entity which is currently being validated. Should that be present here before getting inserted?

Comment: I would simply not use hibernate validation to do that. It looks like a business rule that should be checked in a specific use-case, rather than a check that must be done each time an entity is persisted or updates (like verifying that a given field is not null or that it is positive). Instead, I would explicitely check that the pickList contains the value, and then persist the entity.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a business rule. A field like gender can have two values "Male" or "Female". These values are stored in a database and will not change frequently. It's only a matter of where we keep these values. I could have used a property file or hardcoded the values in the validator class. So this is more of a data integrity check.

Comment: Then use an Gender enum rather than a String, and/or create a Gender table containing Male and Female, and add a foreign key constraint on your entity's gender column.

Comment: We are trying to add all static lists such as gender/state codes/languages in a single table. These values are used to render radios, dropdowns or checkbox lists on User Interface. Are you hinting that this data integrity should be the responsibility of UI layer rather than the persistence layer? I have another scenario where in I have to check for valid zip/county/state code combination in an address object. This combination is stored in the database. How do I go about validating this using hibernate validator?

Comment: My point is that Hibernate validator is not the right tool for this job. Implement this rule as a business rule, and call it explicitely in the `createAddress()` and `updateAddress()` services. Storing unrelated values in a single table is not a good idea. Normalize your data, which will, for example, allow the use of foreign key constraints to check that a value is allowed.

Comment: There should be a way to access database while validating. Checking data integrity as a business rule might be maintainable if I am explicitly calling methods like createAddress() or updateAddress(). In case of composite entities persistedby hibernate, it will be cumbersome to run such data integrity checks on each and every nested entity. Since such validation rule will be a constant in the system, it can be part of the entity. The question might be more inclined towards how to achieve the scenario technically, rather than a good design practice.

Answer (score 2):

The JPA spec says:

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager
>   or Query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the
>   same persistence context.

And it also says:

> Automatic validation using these constraints is achieved by specifying that Java Persistence delegate
>   validation to the Bean Validation implementation upon the pre-persist, pre-update, and pre-remove
>   entity lifecycle events described in Section 3.5.2

So the spec explicitely says that you shouldn't use the entity manager in a life-cycle event, and that automatic validation is performed using life-cycle events. So, you can't use the entity manager in a validator.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the previous answer no EntityManager operations should be executed during life cycle events. If you really want to do it you should open a tmp session. See also https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AccessingTheHibernateSessionWithinAConstraintValidator

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following code in my validator and seems to work fine:

```
public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if(value == null){
        return true;
    }
    //This method uses entityManager to fetch a list from database
    TransactionTemplate txTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);                
        txTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        Map<String, String> pickList = (Map<String, String>) txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
            public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                 return pickListProvider.getPickList(picklistName);
            }
    });
    return pickList.contains(value);
}
```

I understand that this seems to be contrary to JPA spec, but I'm sure that the data being fetched by this validator is part of the master data and will not lead to isolation issues like phantom reads.